# Listar usuários local do windows com forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Boas users!

Eu criei uma aplicação para criar usuários do windows local em massa, obtive ajuda aqui de alguns usuários foi show de bola, mas estou com um probleminha agora:

eu preciso fazer uma condição onde eu antes de chamar o método para criação dos usuários, eu quero verificar se o usuário já existe. Já pesquisei muito e não obtive sucesso.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Poste o codigo que ache pertinente.

Comment: @vik tenho nem ideia do código ainda, para fazer essa listagem.

Answer (score 1):

Eu mudei uma informacoes de um codigo que tenho para listar Grupos e deu certo, vou postar aqui para que outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema.

```
DirectoryEntry machine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",Computer");



var results = machine.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Where(r => r.SchemaClassName == "User").OrderBy(r => r.Name);
```